# special character in a a tags href link when making a link to an email is not parsed right to the mail client

Tags: firefox

I got the bug as Molizza Firefox post

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=230096

I would like to know this bug is fixed or not? anybody still has this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like some kind of UTF-8 issue. Either the mail is sent using UTF 8 (and interpreted as ANSI) or something similar happens when parsing DOM or evaluating the link.

But in general, you shouldn't put non-ANSI-characters into URLs. Instead, escape them using `%HEXCODE`. Also space characters should be replaced using `%20` or `+`.

Most programs (like web browsers or in this case Outlook) accept space characters and other things, but you still shouldn't rely on that behavior as it might go wrong (as it did here).

Answer (score 0):

Here is my html code

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
<a id="test">test</a>
<script>
function buildMailTo(address, subject, body) {
    var strMail = 'mailto:' + encodeURIComponent(address)
                   + '?subject=' + encodeURIComponent(subject)
                   + '&body=' + encodeURIComponent(body);
    return strMail;
}
var strTest = buildMailTo('abc@xyz.com', 'Foo&foo', 'Chỉ sau 2/3 thời gian làm bài thi tốt nghiệp môn Toán, nhiều thí sinh đã ra khỏi phòng với gương mặt phấn khởi. Nhiều em tự tin sẽ được trên 8 điểm.');
document.getElementById('test').href = strTest;
</script>
</body>
</html>
```